# What is best Guide/Resources for Magento 2 custom extension development?

Tags: magento2, extensions

It looks the major structure changes in `Magento 2.x`, I was developing a custom extension for `Magento 2.x`. But it looks nightmare to me.

- What is best approach to start on `Magento 2.x` custom extension ?
- What are the major changes there ?
- Best follow up guide or resources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching many hours i found some very useful resource for this.hope these are useful to others too.

https://github.com/aleron75/mageres

https://github.com/benmarks/magento-resources

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/

http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

Answer (score 1):

There is this book **Magento 2 Development Essentials** which helped me a lot in understanding the changes from magento 2. It has some examples, pretty nice, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The official guide for PHP developers is [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html)

Official guide for Front end developers is [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html)

Also, there are [tools to migrate your code to 2] (https://github.com/magento/code-migration) if you already have an extension in M1.